# mySQL jar name and location

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I wanted to know, What jars do I need to have to connect to MySQL, and Where can I download it?

I googled it but there are so many of'em. Can somebody tell me what class DO I need to use.?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar (or if you want some other version, you can download that). Here is where to find them:

http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.tar.gz/from/pick?file=Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.tar.gz&mirror=pick

For an example of how to connect using `mysql`, there are plenty of tutorials, here's one to check out:
http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003090401&page=1